# How to change CDialog icon in response to mouseover?

Tags: c++, mfc, icons, mouseover, cdialog

How can I change the application icon on mouseover?  I want to put some menu items in the system menu of my CDialog, and I want the icon to highlight when the user mouses over it to indicate that it is a user interface component (similar to how recent versions of firefox have the firefox menu in orange and when you mouseover it, it highlights).

**UPDATE**

By "application icon" I mean the system menu icon.  Also I just came across the CMFCRibbonApplicationButton class which, while not the system menu, also looks promising.

Comment: Define `application icon`. Application is an invisible thing, visible stuff includes windows, appbar, system tray icon etc.

Comment: Do you mean the Icon in the system menu, or an icon on a control that is embedded in the dialog?  If the latter, have a look at this class:  http://irms.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/irms/IRMS/Controls/PicButton.cpp?revision=1.3&view=markup  Caveat:  This is code I wrote over 8 years ago, and I have not really looked at it since.  But it was a CButton that had a bitmap resource that would change on mouse up/down events.  Should be similar to what you need.

Comment: I mean the icon in the system menu. Updating question now.

Answer (score 1):

Check [WM_NCHITTEST](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645618%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for `HTSYSMENU` code and then call [SetIcon](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9cb3b7b5.aspx).

Comment: Good one. +1. Correcting the spelling of `HTSYSMENU` now ;) ... although, does that work for the icon specifically (i.e. not the system menu, but hovering over the icon as asked).

Answer (score 0):

There is the code to implement MouseOverEvent: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/mouseenterleave.aspx When you catch the event you can do whatever you like.

Comment: You sure that works in the non-client area? I'm pretty sure it won't, but I could be wrong.